# How do i get variables/functions of another class in BaseHTTP class "WebServer"

Tags: python, basehttpserver

## renegade.py (main before)

```
import socket, re
from prerequisites import *
import datetime,random,sys,time,os,pickle,urllib
from threading import *

class Renegade():
    def __init__(self, settings, main, db):
        self.settings = settings
        self.main = main
        self.fds = fds(self.settings, self.main, self)  
        self.somedict = {}
```

## webserver.py

```
import string,cgi,time, threading, logging, sys
from os import curdir, sep
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import pickle
from renegade import Renegade

class WebServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    #super(WebServer, self).__init__() # if i put it here: NameError: name 'WebServer' is not defined
    logger = logging.getLogger('httpd')

    def __init__(self, settings, main, renegade):
        super(WebServer, self).__init__() # i guess here its right, but that tells me: TypeError: must be type, not classobj
        self.settings = settings
        self.main = main
        self.renegade = renegade


    def do_GET(self):
        print self.renegade.somedict = {} # want to display this but how do i get somedict of renegade.py (Renegade) class?
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `webserver.py`:

```
from main import Main
Main.SomeFunction()
```

You need the import so that `webserver` knows about `main`'s classes.

---

With regards to your latest problem, you can do either

```
BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self)
```

or else replace `class WebBrowser(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):` with

```
class WebBrowser(BaseHTTPRequestHandler, object):
```

(The problem is that you have an old-style class in the hierarchy, which is calling the `super` call to fail. FYI googling the error can often help.)

Comment: well doesnt work AttributeError: class Main has no attribute 'temp', 'from main import Main' class Main():
 def __init__(self, settings, main, db):
  self.temp = {'bla':'foo'}

Comment: @DeadSix: my answer solved your question. This new thing is a different reason; if you post the (full) code for it in your question then I can take a look.

Comment: @Deadsix: two things. __Thing one__: remove all the `import *` and replace them with named imports. This will save you so many headaches later. __Thing two__: uncomment the `__init__` method that you have commented out, and add the following line at the top: `super(WebServer, self).__init__()`.

Comment: @Deadsix: (naturally, if you try to access `self.renegade` without first defining it, you will get an error)

Comment: i did put the super() at top, and it gives me a new error (see Question, ive updated it)

Comment: @Deadsix: the second place is right; you have an old-style class in your hierarchy. I guess the easiest solution is to use `BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self)`. Does that work?

Comment: i googled it for hours... And yet i gave up, and now use Twisted